# JSONArray Return first row from php and sql server database

Tags: android

Please help me for return all rows and view in listview:

```
ListView List;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> StudentList;
private static String url_course_student = "http://10.0.2.2//mzn/android/StudentCourse.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_Student = "Student";
private static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
private static final String TAG_ModName = "ModName";
JSONArray Student = null;

public StudentCourseFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_student_course, container, false);
    List = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listStudentCourse);
    StudentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    rootView.requestFocus();
    rootView.setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
        {
            if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
            {
                Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
                getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title);

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    } ); 

    new StudentCourseClass().execute();

    return rootView;
}

class StudentCourseClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loding ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_course_student, "GET", params);

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {

                Student = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Student);

                for (int i = 0; i < Student.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = Student.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_ModName);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_ModName, name);


                    StudentList.add(map);
                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        getActivity(), StudentList,
                        R.layout.course_customize, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                            TAG_ModName},
                        new int[] { R.id.lblName, R.id.lblView });

                List.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });
    }
}

}


<per>

<?php

$response = array();
$_POST["StudentID"]='4470';

if (isset($_POST["StudentID"])) {

$StudentID = $_POST['StudentID'];

require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM [DailyExams] where UserID = " . $StudentID;

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $db->conn, $sql );

if ($stmt) {

$rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt);

if ($rows  === true) {

$response["success"] = 1;
$i=1;

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($db->conn, $sql);

$result = array(); 

do {
while ($result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

   $Student = array();
            $Student["ID"] = $i;
            $Student["ModName"] = $result["ModName"];
            $Student["ModName"] = iconv('Windows-1256', 'UTF-8', $Student["ModName"]);

            $response["Student"] = array();

            array_push($response["Student"], $Student);

            print_r( json_encode($response));
            $i= $i + 1;
}
} while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt));

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($db->conn); //Close the connnectiokn first

echo json_encode($response);

    } else {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No Student found";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Student found";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {

$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

echo json_encode($response);

}

?>

</per>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more concise, and moved the question in the question body. Please edit in your code sample to apply a proper code style and to properly indent it as it is unreadable. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Custom List for that purpose.

First of all create a model class:`StudentModel`

```
public class StudentModel{
    public  String name, id,  image, description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

After that An adapter class: `StudentAdapter`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;


public class StudentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    private List<StudentModel> list;
    private final Context context;

    public StudentAdapter(Context context, List<StudentModel> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list=list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return list.indexOf(list.get(position));
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        TextView textView_name;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.artists_item, parent,
                false);

        textView_name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_artist);
        textView_name.setText(list.get(position).getName());

        return itemView;
    }


}
```

Now in Your Activity:

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_course_student, "GET", params);


        try {

            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {

                Student = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Student);

                for (int i = 0; i < Student.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = Student.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_ModName);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_ModName, name);


                    StudentList.add(model(TAG_ID, TAG_ModName));
                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

```
    pDialog.dismiss();

getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

                 StudentAdapter adapter=new   StudentAdapter(getActivity(),StudentList);
                                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


                                }

        }
    });

}
  private StudentModel model(String id,String name)
    {
        StudentModel m = new StudentModel();
        m.setId(id);
        m.setName(name);
        return m;
    }
```

Comment: thank you but  JSONArray return 
[{"ID":1,"ModName":"Java"}] only

Comment: @AbdulWahabBinYahya only a single object?

Comment: @AbdulWahabBinYahya Ok but if theses records increases your results will be viewed on list. :)

Comment: when run php code page
Return each row in table  echo (json_encode($response));

put in android return first Row JSONArray

Comment: The error in ـ  json_encode($response);

when print data in php file